# CrossValidated in classrooms?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using CV as part of a statistics course](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/using-cv-as-part-of-a-statistics-course)

Along the lines of [promoting and improving CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/improvement-drive-cross-validated?cb=1), how can it be used in the college classroom? I know that some stats departments teach their students to think as statistical consultants. Maybe an assignment for such students could be to answer some questions on CV?

Comment: **Related**: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1000/2970